# Is there a way to add numbers in python by entering them in the same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't find anything on the internet about it and I am asking if there is a way to add(or perform any operations) numbers by entering them in the same line and not having to enter to input again?

I know this works:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter first number: ")
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: ")
sum = num1 + num2
print("The sum is ",sum)
```

But I would like to ask the user to input the two numbers together

```
lenwid = float(input("Enter length and width: ")
```

then performs the operation desired.

> Enter length and width: 5 10

> The area is 50 sq units

Answer (score 0):

You can try - Passing multiple values using list comprehension

```
num1, num2 = [int(x) for x in input("Enter length and width: ").split()]
```